# Problem writing into a database

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, xcode

getting errors when trying to write into a SQL database using the 2 following functions:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

   NSString *dbName = @"TrackDate.sqlite";
    [dbName retain];

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                                             
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbName];
    if (exists == false) {
        NSString *resourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:dbPath error:nil];
        [fileManager release];
    }

    sqlite3_open ([dbPath UTF8String], &database);
}
```

Variables are being used

```
char *sql = "Insert into Daten (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Speed, Course, Time) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL);

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [latitude UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [longitude UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [altitude UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [speed UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [course UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt)) {
        recordLabel.text = @"Error!";
    }

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Comment: what about telling us what "errors" you are getting?

Comment: yeah, it often helps to tell us the errors you want us to help with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *sql = "Insert into Daten (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Speed, Course, Time) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

You have an error in the SQL statement: six columns, seven placeholders.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the reason. Now it runs great

Answer (score 0):

You pass six field name and assigning seven values.

replace this

char *sql = "Insert into Daten (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Speed, Course, Time) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

with

char *sql = "Insert into Daten (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Speed, Course, Time) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    char sql[1000];
write values according to your self.
    sprintf(sql, "Insert into *your table name* values ('%s', '%s')",[productId UTF8String], [folderId UTF8String]);
```

//path will contain the path of your database location.

```
    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath] ;
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {   
            //NSLog(@"%s",sql);
            sqlite3_step(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: the code you propose is less safe than what the questioner has. Your version can overflow `sql[1000]`, and is vulnerable to SQL Injection. What's more using `prepare` on a statement with no placeholders doesn't really make sens.